# How to assign priority to kafka source topics in low level kafka streams processor topology

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, apache-kafka-streams

There is a topology implemented using low level kafka streams API. It consumes events from two topics HighPriorityTopic & LowPriorityTopic. The events has to be consumed in such a way that the events in LowPriorityTopic should be consumed only when there are no events in HighPriorityTopic. How to achieve this?

Comment: This is not supported atm. Feel free to file a feature request: https://issues.apache.org/jira/projects/KAFKA/issues

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax: You might want to write this as an answer, not as a comment to the question.